# Jquery Tables manipulation

Tags: jquery

Im working on table & cells.
I have a button in each cell. So, I wanna hide all the buttons in table cells. And it shows when user clicks on a perticular cell, user can see the button in the perticuar table cell.

(im using jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Attach a class to all buttons and hide() them, then bind a click event to each cell that contains an anon function that causes the button that is a child of the clicked cell to display. My jQuery is rusty but base it on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').hide();
  $('.cell').click(function(){
    $('.button').hide(); // hide all others if showing already
    $(this).find('.button').show();

  });

});
```